# Android - Remove totally underline from EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this `EditText` on my `Android` app:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/txtName"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
     android:text=""
     android:hint="Name"
     android:width="150dp"
     android:height="50dp"
     android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners" />
```

and when I type something on it, the word it's underline.

I know that it is because of the auto suggestion of Android and it can be solved with  `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` so **please avoid answers that just say to me what I know**.

**The problem** comes when I add the attribute that I put above to the `EditText`, because it change its form. For example, if the `EditText`its like:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────┐
|                                           |
└───────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

when I add the attribute `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` its form change to something like this:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────┐
└───────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

And on the bottom of the layout a white block appears (maybe because the `EditText` are white, I suppose that) with a size more or less as the `EditText` that has changed (the second one) but in this block I can't interact. Something like this:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────┐
|                 LAYOUT                    |
|                                           |
|    //EditText changed                     |
|  ┌──────────────────────────────────┐     |
|  └──────────────────────────────────┘     |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|  //Block at the end of the Layout         |
├───────────────────────────────────────────┤                                           
└───────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

With the attribute `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` when I type words manually on the `EditText` they aren't underline but when I use the `Swype` function of my keyboard, they are underline again.

Also, I don't want that this attribute changes the `EditText` even more if it creates a block on the bottom of the Layout.

Therefore, **what I want to know**:

**1)** Is it possible to totally remove the underline of the words that are entered into the `EditText`? It doesn't matter if it is manually, by `Swype` or whatever.

**2)** How can I remove the underline of the words of my `EditText` but without changing the `EditText` or that a block appears on my `Layout`?

**EDIT:** Here I add two photos in which you can see the problem:

**1)** Before add the attribute.

[image]

**2)** After add the attribute.

[image]

**EDIT 2**: Here it's my `rounded_corners` background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <padding
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>

</shape>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post an image oh what you mean

Comment: @tyczj I did a representation of what happens with ASCII because I can't add an image right now. I expect it is clear enough.

Comment: no, it is not. upload images and link from post.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Question edited with photos.

Comment: @tyczj Question edited with photos.

Comment: set a hard height and not `wrap_content`

Comment: @tyczj What do you mean with `hard height`?

Comment: @Error404 `android:layout_height="75dp"`

Comment: @tyczj Now the block at the bottom of the layout doesn't appear but the EditText its bigger than before.

Comment: @tyczj What could be the problem of the block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION TO SOLVE THE PROBLEMS WITH MY `EditText`**

Finally, I found a solution to solve the problem of my `EditText`. I put it here because I think it could be helpful to another people. I'm going to divide the problem in two solutions.

First of all, **how to remove the white block at the bottom of my layout**.

As `N.T` said (Thanks!), I just have to change my `android:layout_height` of my yellow layout to `match_parent`.

Second one, **how to make my `EditText` not to be so reduced**.

I just have to remove these attributes:

```
android:width="150dp"
android:height="50dp"
```

And add these others:

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
android:minLines="2"
```

So the full `EditText` now it's as follows:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/txtName"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
     android:text=""
     android:hint="Name"
     android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
     android:minLines="2"
     android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners" />
```

---

**SOLUTION TO TOTALLY STOP THE UNDERLINE**

You have to add `textVisiblePassword` to your `inputType`. With this value you only will be able to type letters one by one, so the underline won't appear.

It don't let you to use `Swype` mode to type words, so the underline never appears.

The `inputType` have to be like:

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
```

Comment: textVisiblePassword is the key ingredient.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your lack of top/bottom padding on the `EditText` is caused by 2 factors:

1 - the original `EditText` has a `9-patch` image for the background with padding built in. I can't possibly know how your `rounded_corners` drawable is built, but I tend to believe that is not a 9-patch image (or if it is, there's no padding built in)
2 - I think `EditText` allocates some space around the text, so that it could display certain extra elements. For example a line underneath the text, used when suggestion mode is enabled. When suggestion mode is turned off, that space is not needed anymore.

Any of the two being present, would preserve some padding on the text. Take them both away and there's no padding (of course, we don't count any explicit top and bottom padding set on the `EditText`).

So the solution would be either build your background image as 9-patch and include the padding in it (you can take the original background as example) or set some padding explicitly.

For the white area on the bottom of the screen - is your yellow-ish layout set to `wrap_content` for height? If yes, set it to `match_parent` to not depend on the height of the contained elements.

Comment: I solve the problem of the block changing it to `match_parent` as you said. Thanks! But I still have the problem with the `EditText`. I edited my question with `rounded_corners` on it. Please look it and tell to me what I can do. I didn't understand very much your solution provided. Thanks again!

Comment: Since you are using an xml drawable, you just need to change/increase padding specified in the padding tag as needed. Just pay attention, because it might conflict with any padding you manually set for teh `EditText` when you actually use the control. On the other hand, for more complex backgrounds, a 9-patch image can be used - it is a specially constructed png file with one pixel border used (and removed) by Android.

Comment: I found now a solution to solve all the problems of my `EditText`. I will post an answer with it but I **still have the problem that with Swype the text it's underline**. Do you know how to totally remove this underline? And I upvote you for your  helpful advices. Thanks!

Comment: There are several approaches you can make. I can't really try them out, however. You can try adding the `textVisiblePassword` to your `EditText's inputStyle` (specifically for swype). Or you can play around with textFilter on the same property.

Comment: I don't know how to make it `specificaly for swype`. But it works. Thanks again! I'm going to edit now my answer.